# find with exec : how to perform multistep conditional action on each file

Tags: bash, find, exec

I have bunch of php files in directory structure say /mylibs
I want to run a simple `php -l $file` on each php file which checks for syntax errors

```
find /mylibs -type f -iname "*.php" -exec php -l {} &>/dev/null \;
```

thats step one, the &>/dev/null eats verbose output from php (found syntax errors or not)

The `php -l` returns 0 if no error  is found depending upon which, I want to copy them to some other dir say `/mybin`. To check if this works as expected I tried

```
find /mylibs -type f -iname "*.php" -ok php -l {} &>/dev/null ; echo $? \;
```

but this simply prints 1 on the terminal and does not ask for confirmation (-ok acts same as -exec after interactive confirmation)

What am I doing wrong here ? is it not possible to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`while` loop](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001):

```
find /mylibs -type f -iname "*.php" | while IFS= read -r path
do
    php -l "$path" &>/dev/null
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]
    then
        cp "$path" /mybin
    fi
done
```

Comment: or simply `php -l "$path" &>/dev/null && cp "$path" /mybin` without the ugly `if`.

Answer (score 0):

does this work for u?

```
 find ....|xargs awk '{r=system("php -l "$0" &>/dev/null"); if(!r) system("cp "$0" /path/to/targetDir")}'
```

Comment: I do `find . -type f -follow -name "*.php" | xargs awk '{r=system("php -l "$0" &> /dev/null"); if(!r) system("echo "$0")}` and I get `awk: line 1: runaway string constant ")} ...` I really liked your awk magic :D we just need to make it work :)

Comment: the awk line in your comment has problem. system("echo "$0 `[without " here]`)